# Mask and Image transforms doesn't match with each other for Pytorch dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I want to train a unet model and for custom dataset class I have a problem with image and masks not matching with each other. They are correct image and mask but transforms didn't apply to both mask and image.

I have this custom dataset

```
class UNetDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, image_dir, mask_dir, transform=None):
    self.image_dir = image_dir
    self.mask_dir = mask_dir
    self.transform = transform
    self.images = os.listdir(image_dir)
    
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.images)

def __getitem__(self, index):
    image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, self.images[index])
    mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_dir, self.images[index].replace(".jpg", "_mask.gif"))
    
    image = np.array(Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB"))
    mask = np.array(Image.open(mask_path).convert("L"), dtype=np.float32)
    mask[mask == 255.0] = 1.0
    
    if self.transform is not None:
        augmentations = self.transform(image=image, mask=mask)
        image = augmentations["image"]
        mask = augmentations["mask"]
        
    return image, mask
```

and these transforms.

```
train_transform = A.Compose(
    [
        A.Resize(height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, width=IMAGE_WIDTH),
        A.Rotate(limit=35, p=1.0),
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.VerticalFlip(p=0.1),
        A.Normalize(
            mean=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            std=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
            max_pixel_value=255.0,
        ),
        ToTensorV2(),
    ],
)
```

Tried to visualize them with this

```
def show_random_images(dataset, n):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(n, 2, figsize=(10, 5*n))
    random_numbers = random.sample(range(0, len(dataset)), n)
    for i in range(n):
        random_number = random_numbers[i]
        img = dataset[random_number][0].permute(1,2,0)
        mask = dataset[random_number][1]
        ax[i,0].imshow(img)
        ax[i,0].set_axis_off()
        ax[i,1].imshow(mask)
        ax[i,1].set_axis_off()


    plt.show()
```

But image and mask sometimes doesn't match.